# Como tirar uma lista de um documento

Tags: python, lista

Eu tenho um documento de texto com diversos dados e gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma lista de apenas o que quero.
O texto está assim:

```
Location,Age,Gender,LastName,Weight(kg),Height(cm),SelfAssessedHealthStatus,Smoker,Diastolic,Systolic
VA Hospital,32,Female,Powell,69,152,Excellent,false,82,110
County General Hospital,41,Female,Diaz,70,156,Fair,false,88,114
St. Mary's Medical Center,39,Female,King,62,157,Good,false,76,123
St. Mary's Medical Center,44,Female,Lopez,69,157,Good,true,91,130
County General Hospital,39,Female,Foster,73,160,Excellent,false,80,113
County General Hospital,25,Female,Garcia,58,160,Good,false,76,125
St. Mary's Medical Center,38,Female,Howard,65,160,Good,false,74,120
St. Mary's Medical Center,38,Female,Mitchell,63,160,Excellent,false,79,118
```

Agora estou encalhada, pois sei como fazer a leitura do texto mas não sei como fazer uma lista de apenas aquilo que quero.
Gostaria de fazer p.e:
`sistole=[110, 114, 123,...]` sem ter de estar a por todos os valores, para depois poder calcular médias e fazer gráficos
como faço?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [**`NumPy`**](https://numpy.org/) para isso.

```py
from numpy import genfromtxt

meus_dados = genfromtxt('arquivo.csv', delimiter = ',')
print('Primeira coluna: ', meus_dados[:,0])
```

Observe que você pode criar um Array multidimensional ou, se quiser, pode colocar os índices em um novo Array. Você também pode fazer isso com a mesma **biblioteca**.

Comment: Obrigada, vou tentar